# Algolia Magento Plugin - showing all the products on the category page

Tags: php, magento, algolia

I successfully configured Algolia Magento plugin on my website. I replaced original category page with the Algolia category page with instant search enabled. Problem is, all the products are showing on category page as opposed to showing the products of the related category. Please help me, what I need to be done to achieve the same. Thx! in advance.

Comment: Site URL where you can check the problem
http://www.a1websitetools.com/magento_test/

Comment: When you guys don't know answer either you put question on hold or down vote. Below answer by "Jan Petr" is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set attribute `categories` to Facets:
[image]

It's issue of current version (1.7.2) of the extension. It'll be fixed automatically in next version (>= 1.7.3) and it won't be needed to set `categories` as facet explicitly.

Comment: Please upvote my question, those guys are duffer who put this question "on hold" and downvote. thx! Jan Petr.